# how to solve "Target of URI doesn't exist package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart" in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, facebook-login

i am a noob and trying to run an app that i cloned from github but i am getting this error i tried everything i could find on various sites but couldn't get rid of this error in dart analysis tab:

> error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [flutter_app] lib\login_page.dart:2)

here is the code for  login_page.dart file : https://codeshare.io/5eEKNJ

already added the dependencies such as :

```
   firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1

   cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4

   firebase_core: ^0.5.3

   flutter_login_facebook: ^0.4.1
```

and already created the facebook app and have given the app id and secret key is the string.xml
but the

**Edit:** already tried flutter pub get and restarted the ide and the issue is still there

Comment: 1) Flutter pub get 
2) Import the package if still not works then restart ide

Comment: already done that, still non use

Comment: check .packages file, see if your package is present else reinstall package

Comment: its present in the  C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_facebook_login-3.0.0\lib\flutter_facebook_login.dart

Comment: then it should work. Try with flutter clean and again install packages

Comment: okay i just ran the flutter clean in the root directory of the project and then ran the flutter pub get in terminal and it all still the same

Answer (score 1):

Okay it was confusion with the package name
there are 2 packages
1.flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
2.flutter_login_facebook: ^0.4.1

the first one was causing issues because in the pubspec.yaml the second one was listed under dependencies and not the first one

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

I think You have to get all packages. That’s why you are facing this issue. Just open the terminal from the project directory and run.

1- flutter clean

2- flutter packages get

Boom! Your Error must be solved.

Solution 2

or try

1- Just press Ctrl + Shift + A (Find Action).

2- Search for “Dart Analysis”.

3- Click the icon that says “Restart the Dart Analysis server”

Now, Your red underline disappears from the package import, and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue while using vs code, but not with android studio. In vs code, after writing package name with desired version in pubspec.yaml file, I used import statement in one of dart file in lib directory. Then I went to  Close Folder from File menu. Vs code prompted to save changes. Later, through terminal, I opened the folder in which I was working, after which a pop up dialogue appeared at bottom right of vs code, prompting to install missing plugins. Then I clicked to install missing plugins, which runs flutter pub get on its own, and then the problem is solved.